# Custom Popup Window with image like interstitial?

Tags: android, dialog, popup, ads, interstitial

[image]

How can I show a popup like this interstitial add in Android Studio using Firebase and how to get the image URL from Firebase and when you click on the image it takes you to store.

Or get the image URL from firebase to show the destination URL from Firebase and then when you click on the image to open another site or the Play Store.

And how can I make the image fit device screen plus add the close button?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to customize Admob Interstitial? If so, unfortunately you can not do it, since Admob interstitial ads are full-screen ads and you have no control over it.

You should check Native ads if you need to customize the look and layout of the ads. The Firebase Native ads Advanced is now open to every one to use: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native-advanced

Comment: no, i want to use popup window with image like that interstitial ad

Comment: Did you find a way?